# Overlapping text over an image

Tags: html, overlapping

Ok, so I'm working on my first website and I'm working from a template found on the web.
The pages are divided in 2 columns with div tags. On the left side I have text, and on the right side I have images that form a slideshow. I would like to modify the text div so that it can overlap over the images in a transparent box... HELP! :)

here is the code in the CSS file for the sidebar and content divs

```
#sidebar_container { 
  float: right;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 450px;
}

#content { 
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
  float: left; position: absolute
  padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

to make divs overlap
first the container of both divs should have a relative position
second 1 of them at least should have an absolute position
for example if one is floating to right
the second should have `position:absolute;right:0px;` 
or both absolute with same/overlapped positioning dimensions
+ 1 div can be either floating or has a position , float and position options doesn't work together